# WCF problems with remote use of net.pipe binding

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding

I'm having an issue with a WCF application that I've written.

When both the client and the server are on the same machine it runs fine, however when I try and run it with the client and server on two separate machine (as it is supposed to run) I get the following in exception:

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://vm101.lab.foo.co.uk/VDNService that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>   System.IO.PipeException: The pipe endpoint 'net.pipe://vm101.lab.foo.co.uk/VDNService' could not be found on your local machine.

What I don't understand is the 2nd line of the exception, that it could not find the end point on my local machine. The end point is on another machine, not my local machine isn't it?

I'm using a net named pipe binding (`NetNamedPipeBinding`) rather than an HTTP one.

And the WCF code is hand coded rather than generated (as I understand is the norm, I didn't learn this till after I'd written the application though).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"net.pipe" addresses a local transport.  You need to use a different binding to talk across machines.  You probably want to use netTcp.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879.aspx

Comment: can net tcp do callbacks? The reason I went with net pipe over Http was becasue it allowed for call backs.

Comment: Yes it can. (yadda yadda at least 15 chars)

Comment: How much of a headache is it going to be for me to convert my code from net pipe to net tcp?
Is it just a case of replacing the  NetNamedPipeBinding with NetTcpBinding? or is there more to it than that?

Comment: swapping the binding is probably all you need to do

Comment: That's the beauty of the WCF model!

Comment: That worked thanks a million you just saved my proverbial arse... Client install is tomorrow and I'd just assumed we wouldn't have to worry about the network stack. Bad developer, next time test more...